# Competition grades in Japanese

Tags: english-to-japanese, sports

I need to make a design for competition certificates in a martial art, and I would like to put the grades in Japanese.
I am not sure for instance if this is correct: "二位" for "second place" in the context of a competition.

What is the correct way of saying 1st, 2nd and 3rd place in a competition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To tell the truth, the only people who can decide what to call the prizes are none other than those who are holding this competition.  All anyone here could do is to give examples of what the prizes are "often" named.

Example #1:

優勝{ゆうしょう}・準{じゅん}優勝・第三位{だいさんい}

Example #2:

第一位・第二位・第三位

Note that 一位・二位・三位 without the 「第」 would be **too informal** to use on certificates, plaques, trophies, etc.

Comment: Thank You very much for the fast answer ! So - the best is to use 第 in front of it ?

Comment: @YordanYanakiev Not sure if "best" is the right way to think about it, but it is acceptable and correct, if that's what you mean. Either option can be used.